# How do I get my c++ program to create a new file?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream

I've tried asking around and googling for answers. It doesn't create the .txt file in my documents folders. No matter what I tried I don't get any errors and the code runs til the end of main. 
1. my input is correct. I checked with cout.
2. I'm putting as my dir C:\users\Bryan\Documents\Points.txt

```
int main()
{
//...
std::string filename;
cout << "Enter output filename: ";
std::getline(cin, filename);

ofstream ost(filename.c_str());
if (!ost) cerr << "can't open output file: " << filename << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        ost<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;
        cout <<"got here 6"<<endl;
//...
}
```

I added close(), but forgot the return 0, and it worked one time.
Then I added return 0, and no matter how many times I try it, it won't create a new file, but does NOT throw errors. 
I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Anyone?

```
int main()
{
    cout <<"got here 1"<<endl;

    cout << "Please enter the file name: ";
    char name[90];
    cin.getline(name, 90);

    cout <<"got here 2"<<endl;
    ifstream ifs(name);
    if(!ifs) error("can't open input file ",name);

    vector<Point> points;
    Point p;
    while(ifs>>p)points.push_back(p);
    cout <<"got here 3"<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        cout<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;

std::string filename;
cout << "Enter output filename: ";
std::getline(cin, filename);

ofstream ost(filename.c_str());
if (!ost) cerr << "can't open output file: " << filename << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        ost<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;
        cout <<"got here 6"<<endl;

    ost.close();

    keep_window_open();

      return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Maybe something went wrong with the file (corruption or something like that) .. did you try to restart your computer ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's stupid Avast anti virus. It always asks me to approve running the application, and block many programs, eg, when I connect my smart phone the fire wall blocks my internet connection.

Comment: Just an FYI: I tried it again. Avast interrupts MS c++ compiler gives me the option of running in Sandbox, or normally. In the beginning I was choosing Sandbox, bc it was just one less mouse click. I had no reason not to, since I've been following Stroustrup's text book and the simple programs the first part of the book don't get affected by sandbox. I guess Avast's sandbox will block creating any new files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you forgot to close your file at the very end. Try to add ost.close() to instruct your stream to flush to the file.

Comment: Finally that did it! But Stroustrup says you don't need close(), and that it's actually better code to let the folder close on it's own when the code goes out of scope. What's going on here? Maybe the problem is I put the code in main()?

Comment: @user2904033 That difference in behavior is surprising. The destructor should implicitly close the file. On my Ubuntu with gcc 4.6 (and the corresponding glibc) the file is created, both with or without an explicit call to `close()`, and even if I don't write anything to it. Maybe there's a bug in your C++ implementation (library).

Comment: I am using the std_lib_facilities.h supplied by stroustrup from his website, along with the keep_window_open() function the end of main(). It seems I also forgot to return 0; from main. Do any of these seem likely culprits?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding std::ofstream::out to the ofstream constructor and use isOpen to check if the file is actually open.

```
int main()
{
//...
std::string filename;
cout << "Enter output filename: ";
std::getline(cin, filename);

ofstream ost(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
if (!ost.isOpen()) cerr << "can't open output file: " << filename << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); ++i)
        ost<<'('<<points[i].x<<','<<points[i].y<<')'<<endl;
        cout <<"got here 6"<<endl;
//...
}
```

Comment: That's wrong and wrong. The constructor that takes a path automatically opens the file and the destructor automatically closes it.

Comment: After your edit, my first comment is not relevant anymore. But now: `out` is already the default mode for `ofstream`: [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream). Also, I guess that by “`isOpen`” you meant [`is_open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open)